# python: Convert from PNG to JPG without saving file to disk using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

In my program I need to convert a `.png` file to `.jpg` file but I don't want to save the file to disk.
Currently I use

```
>>> from PIL import Imag
>>> ima=Image.open("img.png")
>>> ima.save("ima.jpg")
```

But this saves file to disk. I dont want to save this to disk but have it converted to `.jpg` as an object. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you want to do with it afterwards?  I would speculate you want to save it to a StringIO object if you want to e.g. return it as part of an HTML response, but you might get a more useful answer if you better describe your use case

Comment: i just need to use that `.jpg` object in oreder to do some scipy operations.

Comment: And just to check, per http://prancer.physics.louisville.edu/astrowiki/index.php/Image_processing_with_Python_and_SciPy, "SciPy can read jpg and png images directly, without using PIL. With SciPy images are stored in numpy arrays, and we have direct access to the data for uses other than visualization. ", so rather than using PIL, you should be able to just do image_data = imread('test.jpg').astype(np.float32) and do SciPy operations with it... unless you're specifically doing something with the jpeg headers?

Comment: Yes. I having using it like that(`.png` in scipy) but some `.png` file tend give errors, some rare ones. So I like to convert them to `.jpg`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do what you are trying using BytesIO from io:

```
from io import BytesIO

def convertToJpeg(im):
    with BytesIO() as f:
        im.save(f, format='JPEG')
        return f.getvalue()
```

Comment: Nice act! Thanks mate! Pretty clever!

Answer (score 7):

Improving answer by Ivaylo:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

ima=Image.open("img.png")

with BytesIO() as f:
   ima.save(f, format='JPEG')
   f.seek(0)
   ima_jpg = Image.open(f)
```

This way, ima_jpg is an Image object.

Comment: I'm getting the error `OSError: cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG`

Comment: @kylefoley76 JPEG does not support RGBA (alpha channel)

Answer (score 3):

To use the `ima_jpg` object in @tuxmanification's approach outside of the `with` statement, use `Image.load()`:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

ima=Image.open("img.png")

with BytesIO() as f:
   ima.save(f, format='JPEG')
   f.seek(0)
   ima_jpg = Image.open(f)
   ima_jpg.load()
```